# rm: cannot remove '/OUTPUTS/*': No such file or directory

Tags: command-line, bash, docker

I am trying to run a docker image on ubuntu on my VirtualBox.
The repo instruction is quite simply:

```
export input_dir=/home/input_dir
sudo mkdir $input_dir
export output_dir=$input_dir/output
sudo docker run -it --rm -v $input_dir:/INPUTS/ -v $output_dir:/OUTPUTS masidocker/public:liver_attenuation_v3_0_3 /extra/run_deep_wholebody_dicom.sh
```

But when i try to run it on my laptop, it gives me the following error:

```
rm: cannot remove '/OUTPUTS/*': No such file or directory
```

Though with this error the docker continues to run

```
Compression will be faster with /usr/local/bin/pigz
Chris Rorden's dcm2niiX version v1.0.20170624 (OpenJPEG build) GCC4.8.4 (64-bit Linux)
Found 119 DICOM image(s)
Convert 119 DICOM as /OUTPUTS/NIFTI_raw/INPUTS_Recon_2__ABDOMEN_20090327103908_3
Conversion required 2.805481 seconds
```

But it fails to write any real result to the output folder. I am trying to figure out why this error happens and how to solve it. Thx!

Answer (score 2):

After running `docker run -it --rm masidocker/public:liver_attenuation_v3_0_3 bash` I found that the `/extra/run_deep_wholebody_dicom.sh` script calls, among other commands, an `/extra/bash1.sh` script which starts:

```
#!/bin/bash
start=$(date +%s.%N)
# dicom to nifty
rm -r /OUTPUTS/*
```

... and continues. It's this `rm -r /OUTPUTS/*` command that's generating the error because the /OUTPUTS/ directory is empty at that point.

As for fixing it, I think the best solution would be to ask the upstream image owner to change the code in `/extra/bash1.sh` to:

```
...
rm -rf /OUTPUTS/*
...
```

The best place for that may be the [Issues page of the Docker repo](https://github.com/MASILab/ALARM/issues).

Short of that, you could run the image with stderr dropped to /dev/null:

```
sudo docker run -it --rm -v $input_dir:/INPUTS/ -v $output_dir:/OUTPUTS masidocker/public:liver_attenuation_v3_0_3 /extra/run_deep_wholebody_dicom.sh 2>/dev/null
```

... where I've simply added `2>/dev/null` to the end of your existing `docker run` command.

Another alternative (thanks to [Stephen Kitt](https://askubuntu.com/users/412264/stephen-kitt) for mentioning it) would be to create a sacrificial file in that directory before executing the script:

```
touch $output_dir/tempfile && sudo docker run -it --rm -v $input_dir:/INPUTS/ -v $output_dir:/OUTPUTS masidocker/public:liver_attenuation_v3_0_3 /extra/run_deep_wholebody_dicom.sh
```